# How can I get/set the height of an hidden element by jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I get/set the height of an hidden element by jquery?

```
<div id="test" style="display:none">...</div>
```

`$("#test").height()` return 0

`$("#test").height(30)` return exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo should do (with quotes):

```
  $("#test").height('30')
```

`$("#test").height()` returns 0 if you don't define a default width in an external css and if the element is hidden.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#test").ccs("height", "30px");
```

or

```
$("#test").height("30px");
```

It is returning 0 because it is hidden.